# Metropolis algorithm Simulated annealing

Tags: algorithms, simulation

Someone could explain me in a simple way why Bruce Hayek theorem guarantee an optimal schedule for Metropolis algorithm?
For me is enough an informal explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? The statement of the theorem? The connection between the statement and the implication "the Metropolis algorithm has an optimal schedule"?

Comment: What is the Bruce Hayek theorem ?

Comment: I say this:
The connection between the statement and the implication "the Metropolis algorithm has an optimal schedule"?